Boat Motor PWM driver
I'm a novice at circuit design and saw this schematic from a video and was wondering what each component did. It's supposed to a PWM motor driver for an electric boat. But there were things about the design that I was confused about, like why was there three cosine signal generators, what were the relays for, how does the POW+ and POW- power sources drive the motor, etc. If someone could explain this circuit it would be greatly appreciated.



To comply with the site rules on  How to reference material written by others, and to help get an answer, can you edit the question to include a link to the source of the schematic.

The best way to understand a circuit is first identify they key components and look up their datasheets.
Note that power apparently comes in at POW+ and POW-.  POW- is connected to GND.
The following is the skeleton of the circuit -- the basic outline stripping out the details which would make it actually work.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
U2, U3, U4 are AUW033N08BG, whose datasheet shows them as 85V MOSFETs which can switch 640 A when pulsed: high power.  Three in parallel allows more current.  Equivalently it's so they can be run at lower temperature: we don't know the spec of the overall unit, which will depend on how cool the MOSFETs are kept.  When on, they connect the source to drain at 3.3mΩ.  R18 (current limit), U1 (gate drive), R21 (current limit), D5 (voltage clamp), R15 (bias) are just things to drive U2.gate from D7, which is assumed to be the PWM input. U1 is a COS4426 which can drive 1.5A: you'd have to ask the designer why they use this instead of any other method. (U3, U4 have same circuit feeding them.) Together then, we have a sometimes-connected-to-ground line, driven by D7, and which can switch high power: let's call this PWMTOGND.
The motor will be connected to MOT+ and MOT-.  D6 controls relay K1, which switches MOT- to either POW+ or PWMTOGND; D5 and K2 does the same for MOT+.  So to run the motor forwards we energise one relay, to go backwards we energise the other.
The relays are driven by MOSFETs (U11, U10), with diodes (D2, D8) to absorb the switch-off currents.  They have the same input circuit as the power MOSFETs: biased low (R16, R11) and prevented from overvoltage by zeners (D4, D7).
Miscellaneous: D1 is a V60100C, whose uses include "reverse battery protection".  All the capacitors are for decoupling.  LED5 and LED1 are indicators with current limit resistors (R1, R10).  The other components are connectors.
